# Is there a versioning plug-in for Brunch? (A Brunch version grunt-rev)

Tags: brunch

I know of static asset versioning plugins for Grunt and Gulp (gulp-rev) which will append a content hash to the filenames to prevent caching issues, but I cannot find one for Brunch.  Is anyone aware of one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Brunch plug-in called [digest-bunch](https://github.com/mutewinter/digest-brunch).  It requires the js references in the index file to be decorated which I don't like, but it does what I need it to do.